# Working of the 74LS76A (JK Flip-Flop)

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I have been trying to understand the logic diagram of the 74LS76A as shown in [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn5476.pdf) datasheet.

Let's say that the flip-flop has been cleared using the CLR input and then it becomes stable as follows -

[image]

Now, let J and CLK become 1, in order to "set" the latch -

[image]

Now, after the propagations through the E gate and the H & A gates, the flip-flop becomes stable as follows -

[image]

Now, let CLK become 0 in order for the flip-flop to become "set" -

[image]

Now, the problem is that in order for the flip-flop to become "set", the outputs of the A & E gates must be 0, which will make the output of the C gate 1, which will then make the output of the B gate 1, which will finally make the output of the D gate 0 -

[image]

But, this can happen only if the propagation delay of the H gate is extremely large as compared to the other gates, because if the middle input of the A gate becomes 1 quickly (due to the output of the H gate becoming 1), then the flip-flop will either remain in the "reset" state, or it will start oscillating forever between the "set" and the "reset" states.

So, does the 74LS76A rely on the propagation delays of the G & H gates being extremely large in order to work correctly?
If so, how is it ensured that their propagation delays are extremely large?

Comment: If you're correct that they need high propagation delay, you can always extend the propagation delay of a gate by chaining more inverters after it. If you need very long delays, you can use a capacitor between a couple inverters. It's not hard to make the delay longer; it's hard to make it shorter.

Comment: @Hearth, that's also what I'm asking. Am I correct that they need high propagation delays, or am I missing something?